# Exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Why?

Tags: c#, exception

Hello got the error in following code..[image]

The method RefeshDataGridView() is static.I run it in a separate thread to refresh the grid and get the latest data from DB table.
I made dataGridView1 static because the method RefeshDataGridView() uses it. Can anyone describe why this error is occurred and how to solve it??

**Update:** If I make dataGridView1 non static then the error is gone.. But then I couldn't use it in the static method..

Comment: Hover over dataGridView1  does it have an object?

Comment: I think the problem here is with you running RefreshDataGridView() on a different thread... is it a windows application?

Comment: Which object is null? dataGridView1, rows? There isn't enough detail on your question to get an helpful answer

Comment: If this is winforms app, you can not access UI elements from another thread

Comment: If it was a cross threading issue then the exception would be different ("Control accessed from thread other than..."). It's probably because dataGridView1 is null.

Comment: By the way, dont forget to do dataReader.Close();

Comment: @alexjamesbrown: Yes this a winform app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose dataGridView1 is `null`. You have to instanciate it or pass an instance of it as a parameter to RefreshDataGridView().